# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10-

Tags: python

I want the program to end if I type *"stop"*.
However, an error occurs when `str(intNum)=='stop'`. What should I do?

The error:

> "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'stop'"

```
intSum = 0

while 1:
    intNum = int(input("Please enter an integer.(If you want to end it, : stop) : ")) 
    intSum = intSum + intNum
    if str(intNum)=='stop':
     break
print("SUM=",intSum)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to take the input as string and use if else loop:

```
intSum = 0
while 1:
    userInput = input("Please enter an integer.(If you want to end it, : stop) : ")
    if userInput == 'stop':
        break
    else:
        intNum = int(userInput)
        intSum = intSum + intNum
print("SUM=", intSum)

# OUTPUT:
# Please enter an integer.(If you want to end it, : stop) : 6
# Please enter an integer.(If you want to end it, : stop) : 3
# Please enter an integer.(If you want to end it, : stop) : stop
# SUM= 9
```

Comment: here code will fail when I pass the input as string type other then `stop` keyword

Comment: @AkshayJain  Yup i know, but thats what the user wants :)

Answer (score 0):

if you type stop, you cannot change it to an integer. I think that is where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

```
intSum = 0

while 1:
    intNum = input("Please enter an integer.(If you want to end it, : stop) : ") 
    if intNum=='stop':
        break
    if intNum.isdigit():
        intSum = intSum + int(intNum)
    else:
        print("Invalid Input")

print("SUM=",intSum)
```

Comment: You cannot convert string 'stop' to int in line 5: intSum = intSum + int(intNum). It will still throw a ValueError

Comment: I've changes the code and now it will display the `Invalid Input` if the input is wrong